# Dynamically add checkbox in asp.net vb from source view

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, checkbox

In this snippet of code I am trying to make 50 checkbox dynamically from the source view

```
<table  width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <% 
        Dim y As Integer = 1
        Dim name1 As String = ""
        For i As Integer = 1 To 5
    %>
    <tr>
       <%
          For j As Integer = 1 To 10
          name1 = "l1A" + y.ToString
        %>
          <td style="padding-top:3px; padding-bottom:3px">
            <label><asp:CheckBox ID="<%=name1%>" runat="server"  onclick="return 
                    calculate(this.id, 1)" /><span class="overlay" ></span></label>   

          </td>
        <%
           y = y + 1
           Next
        %>
     </tr>
     <%
        Next
      %>
</table>
```

Now the problem is that...

As I am trying to give the dynamic name to the checkbox so that i can check it from the back-end but its showing error at `ID="<%=name1%>"`

Tell me how to resolve the problem

Comment: What error does it show?

Comment: Change `ID="<%=name1%>"` to `ID='<%=name1%>'`.

Comment: Please give the error stack trace to easier understanding of the problem

Answer (score 0):

you can try this :

```
 <table  width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <% 
        Dim y As Integer = 1
        Dim name1 As String = ""
        For i As Integer = 1 To 5
    %>
    <tr>
       <%
          For j As Integer = 1 To 10
          name1 = "l1A" + y.ToString
        %>
          <td style="padding-top:3px; padding-bottom:3px">
            <label><input type="checkbox" id="<%=name1%>" onclick="return calculate(this.id, 1)"/><span class="overlay" ></span></label>   

          </td>
        <%
           y = y + 1
           Next
        %>
     </tr>
     <%
        Next
      %>
</table>
```